# Zabbix get IT service statistics using python script (pyzabbix)

Tags: python, zabbix

I need to get information about IT service like:

- Total Downtime Total
- Downtime %
- Total Uptime
- Total Uptime %
- List of outages with dates, start time, end time and duration

How can I get this using Zabbix API and any lib for python?

Comment: Have you created items to track these in your zabbix instance?

Comment: Sure. I have created needed items to track. I can get some info like uptime and downtime using python. But how can I get List of outages with dates, start time, end time and duration?

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI

# Set up the Zabbix API connection
zabbix_url = 'http://zabbix.example.com/zabbix'
zabbix_user = 'your_username'
zabbix_password = 'your_password'
zabbix_api = ZabbixAPI(url=zabbix_url, user=zabbix_user, password=zabbix_password)

# Get the IT service ID
service_name = 'Your IT Service Name'
service = zabbix_api.service.get(filter={'name': service_name}, selectDependencies='extend')[0]
service_id = service['serviceid']

# Get the IT service availability report for the last 30 days
report = zabbix_api.service.getsla(
    serviceids=[service_id],
    intervals={'from': 'now-30d', 'to': 'now'},
    operations=[{'operationid': 'service_availability'}],
    extendoutput=True
)

# Extract the information you need from the report
total_downtime = report[0]['sla']['sla'][0]['okTime'] / 3600
total_downtime_percentage = report[0]['sla']['sla'][0]['sla']
total_uptime = report[0]['sla']['sla'][1]['okTime'] / 3600
total_uptime_percentage = report[0]['sla']['sla'][1]['sla']
outages = []
for outage in report[0]['sla']['outages']:
    start_time = outage['from']
    end_time = outage['to']
    duration = outage['duration']
    outages.append({'start_time': start_time, 'end_time': end_time, 'duration': duration})

# Print the results
print("Total Downtime: {} hours".format(total_downtime))
print("Total Downtime Percentage: {}%".format(total_downtime_percentage))
print("Total Uptime: {} hours".format(total_uptime))
print("Total Uptime Percentage: {}%".format(total_uptime_percentage))
print("Outages:")
for outage in outages:
    print("Start Time: {}, End Time: {}, Duration: {} seconds".format(outage['start_time'], outage['end_time'], outage['duration']))
```